# Сравнение двух xml файлов

Tags: python, xml

Добрый день!
Столкнулся с проблемой сравнения двух xml документов.
Суть:
нужно сравнить два файла, в которых атрибуты могут либо удалятся, либо изменяться, а узлы могут также, либо удалятся, либо добавляться.
Был выбран такой код:

```
from lxml import etree
tree1 = etree.parse('note.xml')
tree2 = etree.parse('note2.xml')
set1 = set(etree.tostring(i, method='c14n') for i in tree1.getroot())
set2 = set(etree.tostring(i, method='c14n') for i in tree2.getroot())
```

Он вроде как работает, но при записи результата в файл выдает ошибку, мол объект типа 'set' нельзя сериализовать.
Подскажите, как записать в файл результат, с сохранением целостности структуры или может есть какие-нибудь готовые компараторы, я просто таких не нашел, хотя мог плохо искать.

Comment: Похожий [вопрос в английской версии SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3007330/compare-xml-snippets)...

Comment: Что вы хотите? (а) узнать эквивалентны ли xml документы (в c14n форме): `c14n(tree1) != c14n(tree2)` где `c14n = lambda tree: ET.tostring(tree, method='c14n')` (б) как сохранить set() объект в файл в каком-то формате? Какой формат хотите? (с) что-то другое? Явно приведите минимальный ввод/вывод, пример кода, полный traceback.